# Removing multiple variables with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

A data frame has the following variables:

```
names(df1)
"var1_a" "var1_b" "var2_a" "var2_b" "var3_a" "var4_a"
```

Am using dplyr to remove variables as follows - one var at a time:

```
df2 <- df1 %>% select(-starts_with(("var1"), everything()))
df2 <- df2 %>% select(-starts_with(("var2"), everything()))
```

Using "dplyr", is there a way to concatenate the two line into one?

Comment: Try using regex, something like `df2 <- df1 %>% select(-matches("^(var1|var2)"))` maybe?

Comment: I don't know if you insist on a `dplyr::select` solution; in base R, `df1[,!grepl("^var[12]",names(df1))]` works fine ...

Comment: @DavidArenburg: or `select(-matches("^var[12]"))`

Comment: @Ben, yeah `matches` is just a `grep` wrapper, see `getAnywhere("matches")` (I'm referring to your first comment)

Comment: @DavidArenburg, you should post your comment as an answer ...

Answer (score 2):

You could construct a regex expression as a per your desire and use the `matches` wrapper in order to filter you columns accordingly (with some modifications from @BenBolker)

```
df2 <- df1 %>% select(-matches("^var[12]"))
```

Or just modify `df1` in place using the `%<>%` pipe

```
library(magrittr)
df1 %<>% select(-matches("^var[12]"))
```

Comment: A variation of your first comment that works too: `df1%>% select(-matches("var1|var2")) ` . Maybe more intuitive for those not familiar with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The variable names can be supplied in a vector:

```
df2 <- df1 |> dplyr::select(-starts_with(c("var1", "var2")))
```